# knex.js not returning when using from nodejs script

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, orm, knex.js

I'm using [knex.js](http://knexjs.org/) as ORM in a nodejs script but when I run it from command line the script "freezes" and doesn't end like it used to before adding knex in it:

```
~/dir $ node index.js projects read-all
freeze
adadazdzadad



^C
~/dir $
```

Thus I have no choice but use `Ctrl+C` everytime to exit the script and I want to avoid that and end the script in a clean way. **But how ?**

**index.js**

```
var args = require('yargs').argv;
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'sqlite3',
  connection: {
    filename: './data.db'
  }
});

console.log(args);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `knex.destroy();` at the end of the script solved the problem.